# jquery.form big size upload ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, upload, jquery-forms-plugin, jqueryform

i have a little problem with internet explorer and jquery.form plugin.
When i try to upload a file > 1MB in IE8 using jquery.form (ajaxSubmit) i get an error and the upload stops suddenly

The description of the error is:

```
textStatus = Aborted
ResponseHeaders = undefined
```

This only occur in internet explorer 8 with file size over 1 MB... in firefox/chrome works fine.

i'm using:

- perl
- jQuery v1.7.1
- jQuery Form 2.94
- Upload method: POST

someone can help me?

Comment: Just confirming... you are using "POST" vs. "GET" correct?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but just for others who came here from google like myself.

It happened to me also when using virtual machine of XP with IE 8 file file-uploader from http://github.com/valums/file-uploader which in IE case fall back to POST instead of XHR upload.

It could  upload files up to 10MB with couple of minutes waiting. Real machine with IE8 could upload 100MB without problems. FYI.